# How to read headers in yaml files?

Tags: python, yaml

how do I **only** read the headers in two YAML files and compare them so that they display the different keys used.
thanks in advance.

here's my code, but it doesn't collect all of the headers just the master ones and the sub ones.

`import yaml`

```
from yaml import load

master_yaml = open('application.yml', 'r')
yaml_dict = load(master_yaml)
master_yaml.close()

collected_keys = []
master_keys = yaml_dict.keys()


for key in master_keys:
    for nested_key in yaml_dict[keys].keys():
        collected_keys.append(key + "." + nested_key)
```

`print(collected_keys)`

it also gives this error 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: I wasn't aware yaml files had headers. Can you show a file snippet example>

Comment: by headers I mean values